# Javascript function activating input fields after hit checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I inherited the old code and trying to add some new functions. For now there is large form in 2 column table, first column has checkbox (yes/no), second input fields / textareas with description.

At checkbox are on the onclick event to check the condition and according to him, activate or block the second column.

I removed all the if statements and made big function full of if which check checkbox state and changing by element id state of input fields.

I wonder if you have idea how write univesal function to activate inputs in td next to that in which the checkbox is.

Function consisting of dozens of conditions to check the condition of one field and changing the status of another is a bad practice thats why I am asking you guys how to bite it.

Comment: Some code would be nice

Comment: Please add a code . Suggestion is to try using something like codepen and provide a link for all to play with.

Comment: Show what you've tried out

Comment: Oryginal code looks more like that `https://jsfiddle.net/d5doe3t4/`

I rewrote it to something like that `https://jsfiddle.net/jmyu1cv4/`

I don't know why it doesn't run, maybe I am too dumb to add jquery, in single file works.